# Click events on Chrome (iPad version)

Tags: ipad, google-chrome, meteor

I am using Meteor in my project and I have the following click event:

```
  Template.Products.events = {
   "click .Product" : function() {
      if(this.InStock) {
         var item = Cart.findOne({Name : this.Name, Price : this.Price});
         if(item) {
               Cart.update(item._id, { $inc : {Quantity : 1} });
         } else {
               Cart.insert({ Name : this.Name, Price : this.Price, Quantity : 1 });
         }
      } else {
         alert("That item is not in stock");
      }
   }
  };
```

However, it does not work on Chrome (iPad version).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `touchstart` event instead of `click` event.